# Adding a link via jquery and making it call a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a link that gets added prior to the page getting loaded. here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    myLink= '<a href="#" id="test" class="test" value="1">SomeLink</a>';
    $("#Control").append(myLink);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            Id = $(this).attr("value");
            ShowId(Id);
        });
```

When the page is finished loading have verified that the links show up correctly. The problem is when I click on the link the function doesn't get called. if I click on any other links that are part of the original page and haven't been added via jquery, the function gets called. The behavior is the same if I use $("#test") instead.

Is there something different I have to do for when I add a link through jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe add an onclick="ready" to the a tag (the syntax probably is not correct, just hinting as i'm just learing jq)

Comment: @DejanBiljecki, I appreciate that you're just learning jQ, so I'll be gentle.  Using any inline JS with jQ is ugly and pointless.  See the answers below by VisioN and Sven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is the most correct way:

```
$(function() {
    $("<a />", {
        href: "#",
        id: "test",
        className: "test",
        text: "SomeList"
    }).data("value", "1").on("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).data("value");
        // ...
    }).appendTo("#Control");
});
```

Note, that `value` attribute is not valid for anchor elements, so I suggested to use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for that.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/N3vKS/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
    // whatever
});
```

Change the selector 'body' to whatever is the highest common parent.